# ACL with multiple server - Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I am using ACLs and use-server directive with if condition: Example:

```
acl olay12 url_sub list
use-server anadolu if olay12
```

I want to add another server to if condition on line 2. If I use or like this:

```
use-server anadolu or server2 if olay12
```

It doesn't work. I know I can use use backend directive but is it possible to add servers to this condition with use-server ?

Thank you

Comment: I'm looking for the same answer, but still didn'find. It looks, like from this topic from 2012 nothing changed: https://serverfault.com/questions/475367/force-use-of-a-certain-subset-of-backends-in-haproxy What we need is directive like "no-use-server xx if abc", or possibility to use multiple "use-server" (not working - only first matched "use-server" rule is used).

Answer (score 1):

The HAProxy documentation is clear about the *use-server* directive. It accept only one server.

https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/1-8r1/onepage/#4.2-use-server

If you want to redirect requests to a server OR another one, that means you want to balance your requests, so you should use the balance mechanism.